# CSS Dropdown Menu Breaks When Setting Left Property After Position Absolute

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm currently working on a CSS Dropdown menu and I've run into the following issues:

1. Each successive sub menu overlaps its parent menu by an increasing amount.
2. Attempting to fix item 1 by setting the `left` attribute (each submenu already has `position:absolute`) does not work and throws off the position of the menu wildly.
3. Whenever a submenu is shown, the `right` padding is automatically increased causing a gap between the menu and the bottom border of the menu items.

In the CSS I use `display: table-*` (the star being any of the table-related display values) in order to make vertical centering of text easier and to more easily keep the selected menu item at the top of the list (see `display: table-header`).

I would really like to know both solutions *and* causes for the above issues.

For reference, I've created a fully functional [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OpnSrce/HSh5n/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/xUWdj/

Changes made:

1. Got rid of all the table displays, the only reason you were using it was for vertical alignment, you can utilize `line-height` on the `<a>`'s instead.
2. All submenu `<ul>`'s now are positioned based off it's parent by `left: 100%;` & `top: 0;`

You should now be able to style/position the rest of the menu to how you want it.

Edit:

Here's a version that allows you to continue using the `table-group-header` http://jsfiddle.net/HSh5n/2/

1. Changed `li a { display: block; line-height: 30px; }`
2. Added margins to move the `ul`'s to `-42px 0 0 130px`

I guess the biggest thing with tables is that since they're inline elements, you can't assign `position: relative` to table-cells, so that's why you couldn't use the `left` or `top` properties. I haven't browser tested this, but I'd always double check if you go this route.

Comment: While this approach works, it harms the "stateful-ness" of the list. Without the ``display: table-header-group``, the list order gets resorted on hover.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't be able to manipulate the order of the DOM so that the `li` that you'd like to be active would be the first one? Then on `#dropdownMenu:hover` just show the rest of the `li`'s, similar to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xUWdj/2/

Comment: If you absolutely can't use scripts to manipulate it, you can always just tweak the margins like with this fiddle, I believe it's what you'd be looking for with keep most of the table display: http://jsfiddle.net/HSh5n/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you add right border to your li a{...} you can get an idea about what's causing the overlaps.

```
li a {
    display: table-cell;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #cccccc;

    border-right: solid 1px #cccccc;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(89,87,87,0.9);
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```